How install Ubuntu 24.04 in OEM mode with a temporary OEM user?
Following https://github.com/canonical/ubuntu-desktop-provision/blob/main/docs/oem-provisioning-24_04_1.md I am able to install an OEM version of Ubuntu 24.04.
I want to configure some of settings prior to the end user installing a "normal" user. In previous versions of Ubuntu I was able to achieve this using a temporary "oem" user. Just wondering if it is possible to create such a temporary "oem" user with Ubuntu 24.04?
Thanks!
